# for loop in bash not working for my script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to use a variable instead of #0 #i so that awk command runs for different variable but its not working in the code below.can any one help?

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0;i<2;i++))
do
    awk '/VM #0 has been allocated to the host/ {print $0}' p_iqr.txt
done
```

Comment: What isn't working? Where do you use the variable?

Comment: if i use #$i instead of #0 for loop doesnt run

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, so why would you expect that to work?

Comment: Why didn't you show that in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-v` option to `awk` to set a variable. Then construct the regexp by concatenating the variable

```
for ((i=0;i<2;i++))
do
    awk -v i=$i '$0 ~ "VM #" i " has been allocated to the host" {print}' p_iqr.txt
done
```